# React-Native: Passing data when opening the app from a browser

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make that if a user clicks on a link on his phone, if the mobile application is installed, to handle the link. I want to pass the url from the browser to the app and open it in a webview.

For example if clicked on "myapp://something?=stringParam". Is this possible in React-Native? If it is, how can I read the data which is sent?

Maybe getInitialURL from Linking module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can do this with the Linking API.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const url = Linking.getInitialURL()
  .then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url)
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred ', err))
}
```

To enable it on Android you do have to follow [these steps](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters) first.